# Using AJAX with Symfony

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

Let's assume that I have a basic hello world application, and I set a session like a link:

```
$_SESSION['link'] = "https://foo.com";
```

Now, I would like to show this session-link in my page, using twig something like this:

```
  <a href="{{ path(app.session.get('filter)')}}">
```

Well, let's say that now, I need to unset the session, *but* with AJAX.

The first thing I can come up is to update configuration

= Routing

```
AcmeTestBundle_remove:
pattern:  /update/ajax-remove
defaults: { _controller: AcmeTestBundle:update:remove}
```

= Controller

```
public function removeAction(){
  // this is where i am stuck
  unset($_SESSION['link'])
}
```

= AJAX

And I assume, ajax setting would be something like this:

```
function removeAction(){
    $.post('{{path('AcmeTestBundle_remove')}}',               
            function(response){
                    if(response.code == 100 && response.success){
                        //dummy check
                      //do something
                    }

    });    
}
```

ehh, I'm obviously, new at this: any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @Ferhad the question was how to create the script, which can unset a session without doing a page refresh

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `$_SESSION` directly. Use `Session` object: `$this->getRequest()->getSession()`.

You would do in you controller something like this:

```
** PHP **:
public function removeAction(){
    //....
    //either one of these calls
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession(); // Symfony 2.0
    $session = new Session(); // Symfony 2.2+

    $session->remove('link');
    //....

    return new Response("OK", 200); // HTTP-200 status code
}

** HTML **:
 <a id="remove_filter" href="{{ path(app.session.get('filter)')}}">

** JS **:

function removeAction(href){
    $.post(href, function(response){ // you could also use $.get()
        //dummy check
        //do something
        // this is success() callback - means that we have received HTTP-200
    });    
}

$(function(){
    // page is now loaded

    // click handler
    $('#remove_filter').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); // stop default link functionality

        removeAction($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

If, for any reasons, controller throw an error you will receive HTTP-500 status code which will not enter your JS callback.

Check this doc out:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

Comment: Any idea, how to handle the AJAX requests?

Comment: Thanks, but your answer still does not answer my question. Like, the ajax code relies on jQuery's post method, but I am not posting anything, I am clicking on a link, and could you please take a little more time to complete it? I will give you a bounty of 50  once done, even though I am asking for too much, this is something very very important for me. :)

Comment: Ahem, I didn't get that was the issue here. Ok, I have updated the answer with JS click handler as well. As for the "not posting anything", that does not matter - you could as well use GET HTTP method for communication.

Comment: sorry for this, but when I click on the link it takes me to another page

Comment: That is strange. Did you set an ID for your <A> tag (id="remove_filter")? Be careful to execute this whole JS **only** on when your page is "ready". I will now add that to JS code above...

Comment: Link redirection can also point to an error in you JS code. Do you use Firebug?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you reply, and already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297985/how-to-check-if-a-link-is-clicked-using-ajax-jquery question now, at-least if to get the jQUery/Ajax part solved. Anyway, I don't have id for a tag, but I have a span element inside it. I don't know what is happening. firebug does not show me an errors

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38986/discussion-between-jperovic-and-piosoiq)

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to leave office and have left the town for few days. Now I see that you have tried contacting me on chat... sorry I was not there...

Answer (score 2):

**For the AJAX part**

```
$(function() {

     $('#session-button').click(function(){
     unsetSession();

});

});    


 function unsetSession() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ path('reset_session') }}",
            type: "post",
            //data: { deal_id: dealId, rating: score },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                if(response.status == 'success') {
                   console.log('success'); 
                } else {

                    console.log('error');
                }
            }   
        });
    }
```

**In the controller**

```
public function resetSessionAction()
{

    $session = $this->container->get('session');//Symfony 2
    $session->start();//Symfony 2

    $session->set("Link", "");// Symfony 2

    $link = $session->get("Link");

    if(!$Link){
        $response = array(
        'status' => 'success',
    );

    }else{
        $response = array(
        'status' => 'failure',

            );

    }

    $jsonResponse = new Response(json_encode($response));
    $jsonResponse->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json; Charset=UTF-8');

    return $jsonResponse;


}
```