# How to check if a link is clicked using AJAX/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to delete a link without a page refresh, and I would like to jQuery to capture and send http request to a specific URL that does the deleting. But, for this to work, I need to be able to use jQuery/Ajax to get the clicked link and send it as an http request.

this is the link:

```
<a href='http://example.com/delete.php?id=243'> <span class='delete'>delete this</span> </a>
```

Now, this is the jQuery and Ajax in twig template to get the clicked link and send httprequest to delete.php with the id, so that id can be deleted.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".delete").click(function(){
           $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "{{ path('http://example.com/delete.php?id=243'}}",
                cache: "false",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(result){
                    $(".success").append(result);
                }
            });
        });

        }
```

But the above function only makes the page navigate to the link when clicked.

Comment: `click(function(e) {  e.preventDefault();` - the click function takes the Event object as the first parameter, calling it's method `preventDefault` stops the browser from following the link.

Answer (score 2):

Prevent default behaviour of link using jQuery's `preventDefault()`.

Having:

```
<a class='delete' href='http://site.com/delete.php?id=243'> delete this </a>
```

Try:

```
$(".delete").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "{{ path('http://site.com/delete.php?id=243'}}",
        cache: "false",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(result){
            $(".success").append(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Still this is taking me to the specified path.

Comment: You need to bind `click()` to `<a>` element in order for it to work.

Comment: Something related here with `+100` bounty if you are interested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355562/how-to-add-ajax-capabilites-to-symfony

Answer (score 2):

You need to `preventDefault`.

```
 $(".delete").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault()
   $.ajax({
   ..
```

Comment: still redirecting to the specified path.

Comment: @piosoiq Can you add the `delete` class to the anchor tag and just remove the span? If not you need to preventDefault on the anchor tag or add `e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: Something related here with `+100` bounty if you are interested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355562/how-to-add-ajax-capabilites-to-symfony

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I got you right here, but this may help you: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

```
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
     event.preventDefault();

     //your code
}
```

Comment: thanks, but not working for me. I still get redirect to the specified path

Comment: Do you need the full url in href attribute? You could use an anchor instead, so users won't get redirected. EDIT: Or don't use a-tag at all.

Comment: Something related here with `+100` bounty if you are interested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355562/how-to-add-ajax-capabilites-to-symfony